# Handling REST errors in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, jersey

I have written a REST service that deals with errors like this:

```
return Response.status(vr.responseStatus).entity("Oh No")
.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

On the client side, I have called this:

```
var request = $http({
                method: "put",
                url: serviceProvidersURL,
                params: {
                    //action: "add"
                },
                data: item
            });

return( request
  .then( handleSuccess, 
         function(response){
             alert("Here1: " + response);
             alert("Here2") + JSON.stringify(response);
          })
);
```

Both the alerts are failing to deal with the response. In the first alert, I get "Here1: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" and the second alert, I just get "Here2"

If I look at the response in firebug, the "Oh No!" is in the response section and these are the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 06:49:57 GMT
Connection: close
```

The Oh No! is definitely in the response body - I have no idea how to get to it through the client side.

Thanks

Comment: `"Oh No!"` or `Oh No!`? The latter is invalid JSON.

Comment: From the REST service, I just send .entity("Oh No").

And it is definitely in the response body.

But when I try to access response in the client side, it doesn't exist - not even to get the status

Comment: Just to understand better, can you share your service implementation? Did you check your API is executed successfully? From the status code you mentioned below, 400 Bad request means, The API call is NOT successful. There might be some problem with the marshalling logic. Please check your API implementation and share the skeleton code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The API is being called. The REST call doesn't allow duplicates. When I send a unique value, it is successful. When I send a duplicate, the code is returning a bad request by design. The bad request returned by the REST API is definitely being received by the browser as I can see it in the browser console. However. for some reason, my client side  code can't access that response (in the alert lines of code) for some reason.